# Optimization Problem in a game

Tags: optimization

I'm playing a game that has an optimization problem built into it that I am struggling to determine the correct solution for.

In this game, you have a probability to win determined by the function $f(x)$ posted below (e.g., when $x = 300$ you have a 20% chance of success, at $x = 500$ you have a 50% chance).

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if } x < 300 \\
  (x - 300) \cdot 0.0015 + 0.2 &\text{if } 300 \le x < 500 \\
  (x - 500) \cdot 0.001 + 0.5 &\text{if } 500 \le x < 1000 \\
\end{cases}$$

$x$ generally increases linearly with time $t$, i.e. $\Delta x = \Delta t$. You can attempt your first chance to win this game anytime $x >= 300$. However, if you fail, you cannot try again until $x = g(x') + x'$ where $x'$ is the value of $x$ that you last attempted to win with. Additionally there is penalty imposed in that $x$ increases at half the rate as it did before, i.e., $\Delta x = \frac 12 \Delta t$, until you have reached the new $x$ that you can (optionally) try again with, i.e., $x = g(x') + x'$.

$$g(x) = \frac{1000 - x}{10 \cdot 0.86}$$

Ultimately, the goal is to win the game with the minimal amount of time $t$. Given these constraints, how should I best approach solving at what $x$ should I first start attempting to win the game?

I am struggling with how to best approach this problem and the only solution I can think of is to code and run a large number of simulations where I first attempt at $x = 300, x = 301, ...$ and use the large volume of data to find the smallest value of $t$.

*Variance*: I note that an individual's tolerance for variance does come into play. For now I'm assuming that the player does not mind a high variance but I suppose I should also consider the case where a player wishes to have low vairance.

Comment: a) Is $x$ retricted to integers? (I'm asking because you were considering to find the solution by trying out integers.) b) Do I understand correctly that the slow-down by a factor of $2$ is in effect only until you reach the value of $x$ at which you're allowed to try again, and if you wait after that this penalty is no longer imposed? c) Most importantly, you don't define an objective function. In a probabilistic setting, "to win the game with the minimal amount of time" makes no sense. From what you write about the variance, I'm guessing you want to minimize the **expected** time to win?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. a) Yes $x$ is restricted to integers (you can assume $g(x)$ is rounded to the nearest integer). b) Yes you understood that correctly. The slow-down by a factor of 2 is only in effect until you reach the value of x at which you're allowed to try again. c) Yes, you're correct. I'm trying to minimize the expected time to win.

Answer (score 1):

With $x$ restricted to integers, this can be solved by starting at $x=1000$ and working your way back. For each $x$, compute the expected time $t_x$ that it will take to win after you reach $x$ with no penalty in effect. This is the lesser of the expected times for your two options: wait, in which case $t_x=t_{x+1}+1$, or attempt, in which case $t_x=(1-f(x))(t_{x+g(x)}+2g(x))$.

[Here’s Java code](https://github.com/joriki/math/blob/master/info/joriki/math/stackexchange/Question4645976.java) that performs this calculation. The result is that you should first attempt to win at $x=368$. If you fail, you should then always attempt as soon as you’re allowed to, which is at $x=441$, $506$, $563$, $614$, $659$, $699$, $734$, $765$, $792$, $816$, $837$, $856$, $873$, $888$, $901$, $913$, $923$, $932$, $940$, $947$, $953$, $958$, $963$, $967$, $971$, $974$, $977$, $980$, $982$, $984$, $986$, $988$ and from then on every turn.

The expected time to win if you follow this strategy is about $559.82$.